# What is the Gauss part of Gauss-Manin connection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

The definition of [Gauss-Manin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Manin_connection) connection involves de Rham cohomology. Surely, Gauss didn't work with de Rham cohomology as we know it.

So, what was the context in which Gauss came up with this idea?

Comment: One comment: I believe that the name was coined by Grothendieck.  Manin's name appears because he used it in his proof of the function-field case of Mordell (I believe).  I'm not sure what work of Gauss Grothendieck was thinking of.